# Does this derivative make sense?

Tags: coordinate-systems, notation, derivatives

I know that the following derivative makes sense and is
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x^\mu}=\frac{x_\mu}{r}\,,
$$
where $r=|x|$. Does the following derivative make sense?
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial r}
$$
If it does, what is the result?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Actually, I want to compute $x^\mu \partial_\mu$. I thought, I can somehow relate this with $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ by chain rule.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

(note: this post is working with the individual scalars directly and not using the usual index conventions)

No. Partial derivative notation is somewhat misleading. For example, the notation $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_0}$ doesn't mean "the derivative of $r$ with respect to $x_0$"; it means "the derivative of $r$ with respect to $x_0$ when $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are all held constant".

Similarly, the tangent vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$ is not "the vector in the direction where $x_0$ increases"; it is "the vector in the direction that $x_0$ increases when $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are held constant".

In other words, partial derivative notation *only* makes sense when you're asking for the derivative with respect to one variable out of a system of coordinates..

---

Differentials are, in my opinion, much more natural to work with. There is nothing implicitly hidden in the equation

$$ \mathrm{d}r = \sum_{i=0}^3 \frac{x_i}{r} \mathrm{d}x_i $$

and you can rearrange it to your liking in the obvious ways; e.g. if you wanted, you could could multiply through by $r$ and shuffle the terms around:

$$ x_1 \mathrm{d}x_1 + x_3 \mathrm{d}x_3 = r \mathrm{d}r - x_0 \mathrm{d} x_0 
- x_2 \mathrm{d} x_2 $$

and the result would remain true. (no particular reason for this particular form; I just picked something to do more or less at random)

Comment: OK. But, is this then correct: $r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=x^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$?

Comment: $r$ is not one variable in a system of coordinates, thus $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ doesn't make sense. I suppose you could make a new coordinate system using $r$ as one of the coordinates, but then you'd have to use the change of coordinate formulas to relate derivatives in the old and new coordiantes.

Comment: ... and note that if you do so, $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ would only make sense in the context of the new coordinates.